# Is there a Creative Commons collection of country maps in SVG format with corresponding country code?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

For a little hobby project I am looking for a collection of SVG files of maps of all countries in the world separately with the country codes included in the SVG or filename. It would have a structure like this:

- AFG.svg
- ALB.svg
- ...
- ZMB.svg
- ZWE.svg

It would also be nice to have a projection that keeps the size of the countries realistically since I will use them to compare pairs of countries.

I have looked on the following places:

- https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/countries-by-area/ Don't know if it can be used for non-commercial purposes and the countries do not contain the country code.
- https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/ Doesn't have a package containing all the countries, also does not have the country code.

I also found a couple more resources which contain the whole world as one SVG or separate countries but no collection with all of them with country codes included.

Is there a resource which offers use for non-commercial purposes SVG of countries with a way to identify them by country code?

Comment: offhand, i bet wikimedia, openstreetmaps, and the noun project also have versions of this as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [mapsicon](https://github.com/djaiss/mapsicon)

**mapsicon** is a free collection of maps for every country in the world, available in 11 sizes or in SVG.
The maps are named after the official two-letter country codes defined in ISO 3166-1. Basically, that means the United States are named US, Canada is named CA, etc.
If you need to access all those countries programmatically, [here is a gist containing all the countries as well as their ISO code: https://gist.github.com/djaiss/2938259](https://gist.github.com/djaiss/2938259)"

There's also:
[Simple World Map](https://github.com/flekschas/simple-world-map): a simple and lightweight SVG world map, annotated with two-letter country code standard ISO 3166-1 alpha 2. This map is one SVG, not individual SVGs.
and
[Marked-Up SVG World Map](https://github.com/benhodgson/markedup-svg-worldmap): an SVG world map marked-up with ISO 3166 country codes. Path (path) and group (g) elements are annotated with cc attributes containing their country codes.